# Network application works between computers on my wifi, but not others

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

So I just started to learn about socket programming, and I decided to make a very basic instant messenger/chat room. The problem is that when I test the application among machines on the my wifi network it runs fine, but when I go beyond that the client fails to connect. Could it be because of the arbitrary port number I used?

Server:

```
public class MessengerServer {
private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
private static final int PORT=1234;

public static void main(String[] args) throws
        IOException {
    try{
        serverSocket=
                new ServerSocket(PORT);
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Unable to open connection.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    do{
        //wait for client
        Socket client= serverSocket.accept();

        System.out.println("New Client Accepted");

        //create a thread to handle communication 
        //with this client and pass the constructor
        //for this thread the relevant socket
        ClientHandler handler= //ClientHandler extends thread 
                new ClientHandler(client);
        handler.start();
    }while(true);
}
```

Client(containing only what is relevant):

```
public class InstantMessenger extends JFrame implements
    ActionListener{
    private static final int PORT= 1234; 
    private static InetAddress host;
    private static PrintWriter output;
    private static Socket link=null;
    private static byte[] ip= new byte[4]; //this is initialised with my IPAddress
                                   //which will not be shown.     


InstantMessenger(){

    try{
    host= InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException uhEx){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
                (this,"Unable to find host");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    try{
        link =new Socket(host,PORT);
        output=
            new PrintWriter(link.getOutputStream(),true);
        messageArea.append("\nConnected\n");
        }
    catch(IOException ioEx){
        messageArea.append("Unable to connect\n");
        }
}
```

Exception on client end, StackTrace:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at instantmessenger.InstantMessenger.<init>(InstantMessenger.java:70)
at instantmessenger.InstantMessenger.main(InstantMessenger.java:132)
```

Comment: Without the stack-trace it hard to help, please include details of any exceptions thrown

Comment: took me a while but I got it. The exception that is.

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by the connection settings on server. If the connection is set to be on public network, I think by default it's not allowed to accept connections from other network. Also, check if you have any firewall settings that would block the incoming connections from other subnets.

Comment: I am an a home group, and I have even tried turning my firewall off

Comment: Firewall on both client and server could be involved.  Also, are you sure that the IP address for the server that you're using is the correct (i.e., public) address for the server?